# Drop table using SQL and to run migrations on EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I created a table `Documents` using Entity Framework Core and the `Add-Migration` command. I also did some modifications related to foreign key in Table 1 using EF Core migrations and updated the database.

But after some time, I dropped the table `Documents` using a SQL `drop table` command instead of deleting it.

Now, how can I sync up my database with my migration state in code? Is there a command to run set of migration from migration mig1 to mig2 and update database?

Comment: Do you want the database and EF to be synchronized before the change (when the table is not deleted) or after the change (after the deletion is completed)？

Comment: before the change, when table structure was present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that your snapshot is out of sync with your actual database.

To fix it:

1. In your migration snapshot comment out the code that relates to the specific table you deleted.
2. Do a new migration (add-migration) to 'introduce' your previously deleted table to EF
3. update-database to apply your migration

Comment: Will deleting migration code files related to the deleted table affect anything now or in future migrations??

Comment: You'd be better off using the remove-migration command for deleting migrations

Comment: What is the command to remove specific migration. Last I checked -target and -migrate flag does not work for remove or add

Answer (score 1):

1. If it's not too complex, manually recreate the table and then create a new migration to remove it.
2. You can copy the deleted `createTable` code from the migration file. Create an empty migration, paste it into the most recently generated migration file, and then generate the script or execute the update-database command. This would recreate the deleted database table. After that, you can create a new migration removing the line public `DbSet<TableClassName> TableClassNameSet { get; set; }` so that EF Core can track the migration correctly.
3. If the code that creates this table is in a single migration, you can delete the row for this table from the `dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory` table and then run the `update-database` command again.
   a